# MySQL Pivot Prepare Statement AS Integer error

Tags: mysql, string, format, pivot

Probably a very basic error but here is my problem. 
There are users who are giving likes to certain pages of a given document and my aim is to return a breakdown of pages liked per user 
Here are (a simplified view of) the two following tables:

### User table

```
id name
---------
1  Jim
2  John
```

### Vote table

```
userid pageno voteup
1      1      1
1      2      1
2      1      1
2      2      1
2      3      1
```

My desired output would be the following:

```
id name Page 1 Page 2 Page 3
1  Jim  1      1      0
2  John 1      1      1
```

I've made my prepared statement as followed. My aim is to display 'Page 1', 'Page 2' and so on for the column names instead of the 'test' below but as my pageno field is an int i fail in formatting the column name. I have tried various things but with no luck.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(v.pageno = ',
      pageno, 
      ', v.voteup, 0)) AS ',
      'test'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM vote;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT u.id, u.name, ', @sql, ' 
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN vote AS v 
ON u.id = v.id
GROUP BY u.id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I'm sure this is something very basic I am missing. Could you help?
Thanks in advance
[Link to SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcb16/1)

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick although is not dynamic, if you need a dynamic solution.....

```
 select 

n.id,
n.name,
CASE WHEN v.pageno=1 THEN sum(v.voteup) ELSE NULL END as "Page 1"
CASE WHEN v.pageno=2 THEN sum(v.voteup) ELSE NULL END as "Page 2"

from votetable as v

join usertable as n on n.id = v.userid
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Alex, unfortunately the number of pages will vary significantly so I would be interested in knowing if it can done dynamically